# No se puede generar contexto SSPI

Tags: c#, visual-studio, reportviewer

Tengo instalado SQL Server en Windows 10 y corro un sistema en C#. Anda todo perfecto.. pero desde otra PC ingreso al programa, veo los archivos, los modifico y consulto, pero al momento de imprimir con Reportviewer me sale ese error... la documentación que vi no me ayuda... alguien sabe como solucionarlo? Gracias